# How to access User.Identity from Validate method of IValidatableObject?

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-4, ivalidatableobject

I have ViewModel which inherits from IValidatableObject. In this model I have to make custom validation and it's require Session variables and User.Identity. I could not find appropriate way how to access this variables. I thought something about static class where would be getter properties, but I am not sure it's valid way.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found answer.

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

Comment: What if I want to pass certain data to the method Validate.?  how do you do it?